# How to achieve pause & resume functionality for file download?

Tags: c++, .net, download, resume-download

I would like to implement pause & resume functionality for downloading a file both for Server & Client. My Questions are:

What Protocol do I need to implement at server site (It will be .NET) ?
Is there any example, tutorial, library anything that can be helpful to implement this functionality at the client site (It will be in C++) ?

Thanks,
Yuvi

Comment: Why would the server care?  Just stop reading the socket in the client code.

Comment: If server is not able to provide resume functionality.. Then client have to start downloading again from beginning..

Comment: As long as the protocol provides seek / range functionality, all the client needs to do at resume is seek to the right spot in the file. HTTP 1.1 has this functionality, and I believe it can be done in FTP as well.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple download manager using Qt C++, here is [code](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2011/07/simple-download-manager-with-pause.html). Idea is to set "range" http header at client side.

In server side, you need to seek file at particular position as specified in "range" header.

Comment: QT has very good Networking Classes, but for only C++ I haven't found any reference link :(

Comment: how about libcurl (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html), i have not used it my self but looks promosing.

Comment: yes I am going through libcurl and Boost::asio, but not able to find any refernce doc that has functions for http range request.

Comment: I guess you can use following code to set header in libcurl, struct curl_slist *headers=NULL;  headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: text/xml");  There are some example here ->http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html